# Downloading pdf file with a name stored in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a pdf file, I am using `e.CommandArgument` to transmit file but I want to add different header to the file as I have a GUID attached to my filename therefore the `e.CommandArgument` also have a GUID and thus when the file is downloaded it comes with the GUID and I don't want GUID on the downloaded file. So what should change in my Content-Disposition Header?

I am storing the file name without GUID in database with a column name `RecieptFileName`, So if anybody can tell me what should I change in my code to download file with only filename and no GUID attached to it.

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receipt" SortExpression="Receipt">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("filename") %>' Text='<%# Bind("ReceiptFileName") %>' ></asp:LinkButton> //I want to download file with this LinkButton text i.e. ReceiptFileName
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code :

```
protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; Filename=" + e.CommandArgument + ".pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Match/Reciepts/") + e.CommandArgument);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the `content-disposition` header.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to change that but do you have any suggesttions of should I change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one options here.

**Option 1:** Pass multiple values through `CommandArgument` separated by a delimiting char.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("filename") + "," + Eval("ReceiptFileName")%>' Text='<%# Bind("ReceiptFileName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Note : Use `Eval` for binding because using `Bind` to send multiple auguments always gets me the second argument's value (not sure why).

And in your command function access the values using `Split` function.

```
protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
        string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string fileNameWithGUID = commandArgs[0];
        string fileNameWithoutGUID = commandArgs[1];

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; Filename=" + fileNameWithoutGUID + ".pdf");
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Match/Reciepts/") + fileNameWithGUID);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** You can directly access the `LinkButton1` text property like below

```
protected void gridContributions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
         GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
         string strFileName = ((LinkButton)row.FindControl("LinkButton1")).Text;
         ...
         ...
    }
}
```